# How can I exclude a package from yum-cron but not from manual "yum upgrade"?

Tags: linux, yum, mongodb

I've just gone through my servers and installed yum-cron (and then enabled with `chkconfig yum-cron on` since that doesn't seem to happen automatically).

Now I realise that I'm running a MongoDB cluster and that automatically upgrading the mongo-server packages could break and/or corrupt data.

I have considered adding `exclude=mongo*` to my `yum.conf` file to skip all mongo upgrades, but I would love to still be able to run `yum upgrade` manually and get all packages updated.

Is there a neat way of achieving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `/etc/sysconfig/yum-cron`, there is an option called `YUM_PARAMETER=` which you can use to pass `yum` parameters to. For example:

```
YUM_PARAMETER="-x mongo*"
```

The scope of that parameter seems to be limited to the `yum-cron` package.

Comment: Thanks - and found some more at http://samdoran.com/2013/05/17/automatic-updates-in-rhel-6-and-cent-os-6/

Comment: Hello, `/etc/sysconfig/yum-cron` doesn't exist in CentOS7+, but you can directly use `exclude=mongo` in `/etc/yum/yum-cron.conf`.

Comment: What I'm trying to find is, how can I pass `--skip-broken` to yum-cron, any ideas?

Answer (score 21):

The previous Jason answer is working for centos 6.x.

For centos 7 and `yum-cron` package, the config file is `/etc/yum/yum-cron.conf`.
If you wish to exclude some packages from auto-update mechanism, you'll have to add an `exclude` line, at the bottom of the file, in the `base` section.

Example :

```
[base]
exclude = kernel* owncloud* php* httpd*
```

This will override the `yum.conf` options, but only in the `yum-cron` context, which is the goal of this thread.

Comment: Nice man, +1 exactly what I was looking for, I confirm it works in centOS7